# How does enclosure affect sound of guitar cabinet?

Tags: electric-guitar, amplifiers

I found comparison of cabinets that has same speaker and similar enclosure (closed back) but sound is very different.

This [question](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/3351/104) gives factors that affect the sound but for these cabinets, the factors look to be the same.

Comment: Added a link into your post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, different sized and shaped enclosures have different sets of resonant frequencies due to the different path lengths of internal reflections.

Second, ports or vents (less common in guitar cabinets) both change the resonant frequencies and also introduce other subtle high frequency noise components.

Third, internal baffling or lack thereof affects how much and what kinds of reflections come out through the cones.

Fourth, a sealed enclosure actually expands and contracts (very) slightly like a drum, so the type and thickness of materials and the construction choices have a minor effect on the sound.

Finally, with a 2x12 the drivers could be wired in series or parallel and there is a slim chance that a guitar enclosure could have some passive electronics in the signal chain that would affect the tone.

Comment: An addition to the fourth paragraph: the air inside a sealed enclosure also comes into play as it acts as a sort of 'spring' for the speaker cone(s), raising the impedance but smoothing out the frequency range.

Comment: @L3B - but all the cabs were sealed, and there was a difference in sound. All looked about the same contained volume. Maybe the actual dimensions (h,l,w) for the same volume cab.,have an influence?

Comment: @Tim Yes the actual dimensions matter, not just the total volume. Opposite walls and opposite corners both create standing waves between them. That's why I put the word "shaped" in my first sentence.

Comment: It's been a good 50 yrs since I built speaker cabs, apart from a recent 2x10 for bass, on a whim, which works really well. Must've got the proportions right! There must be a good formula, if not from a scientific pov, then from experience. Simply copy the greats?